# Perl - while writing file to Standard Output last line is missing

Tags: perl

I'm learning perl in free time and I'm trying to write simple script that will open and refresh certain file.
The snippet below should open the file and write it to standard output. And it does, but unfortunately, its printing the file without last line.

Any ideas why?

```
use strict; 
use warnings;

my $filesizeold = 0;

while(1){
    my $filesize = -s "input.txt";

    if($filesize != $filesizeold) {
        system $^O eq 'MSWin32' ? 'cls' : 'clear';
        open INPUT, "<input.txt";
        while ( <INPUT> ) {
            print;
        }
        close INPUT;
    }

    $filesizeold = $filesize;
}
```

Comment: It seems odd to have a `while` loop when `$filesize` cannot change inside it... why is there a `while` loop?

Comment: `true` is not recognize by Perl. ALWAYS `use strict; use warnings;` Except that, your script works pretty fine for me.

Comment: I did some corrections. It seems that the problem occur when there's no `newline` sign after last line... Maybe there's something like println instead of print?

Comment: It seems you run an infinite loop, the last line is certainly buffered. Remove the `while(1)` loop.

Comment: no, when I update input.txt, the result is shown immediately

Comment: Try replacing everything between `open` and `close` with `\`cat input.txt\`` to debug

Comment: M42 was right, it was buffering problem. `$|++;` solved the issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Maybe there's something like println instead of print?

Yes there is, you can use `say`.

http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/say.html

> Its printing the file without last line

I think you are [suffering from buffering](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html).